# create multiple processes with fork() that communicate with pipe without using exit() or wait()

Tags: c++, unix, process, pipe, fork

wait(), exit() and signals are forbidden
only pipes allowed
A user gives an integer positive number-N and N-processes are created, father creates a child, that child becomes a father and creates another child and so on. Each one of the first processes (N-1) should wait to finish its process-child first and then itself. The initial process should print "1-My Process ID: ", the next process that's been created the number "2 My process ID:       and my father's ID:" and so on. 
my code. i don't have wait or exit instead i use return(-1).
**but i  didn't managed to print accordingly the numbers *1 my process id..., 2 my process id..., 3 my process id... and so o*n.
any ideas?**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* Read characters from the pipe and echo them to stdout. */

void read_from_pipe (int file)
{
    FILE *stream;
    int c;
    stream = fdopen (file, "r");
    while ((c = fgetc (stream)) != EOF)
    putchar (c);
    fclose (stream);
}

/* Write some random text to the pipe. */

void write_to_pipe (int file)
{
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fdopen (file, "w");
    fprintf (stream, "\n");
    fprintf (stream, " ");
    fclose (stream);
}

int main (void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int mypipe[2];
    int j = 1;
    int i;

    cout << "\nassume father is by default the first process\n" << "Please enter how child-processes you want: ";
    cin >> i;

    for( ; j < i; j++)
    {

        /* Create the pipe. */
        if (pipe (mypipe))
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
            return (-1);
        }

        /* Create the child process. */
         pid = fork ();
        if (pid == (pid_t) 0)
        {
            /* This is the child process. Close other end first. */
            pid = getpid();       
            close (mypipe[1]);
            read_from_pipe (mypipe[0]);
            printf("Child's ID: %d\n",pid);       
            sleep(0);
        }
        else if (pid > (pid_t) 0)
        {
            /* This is the parent process. Close other end first. */
            pid = getpid();        
            close (mypipe[0]);
            write_to_pipe (mypipe[1]);
            printf("Dad's ID: %d\n",pid); 
            sleep(0);
        }
        else 
        {
            /* The fork failed. */
            fprintf (stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
            return (-1);
        }

    }//end for 
    //close (mypipe[0]);
    //write_to_pipe (mypipe[1]); 
   // printf("Dad's ID: %d\n",pid); 
    return (-1);
}// EOP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion could be simpler than iteration because you want each child to in turn create another child. The trick to avoid `wait` is to have each *parent* to read on the read end of the pipe, and to have the child to close the write end just before returning without writing anything. Because the read will be blocked until either something has been written or the other end is closed.

You cannot be sure of the order in which the processes will actually end because you do not call wait, but you are sure that a parent cannot end before its childs has terminated  its job.

Code could be:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

int start_child(int i, int j) {
    int my_pipe[2];
    pid_t parent_pid, pid;
    /* Create the pipe. */
    if (pipe (my_pipe))
    {
    cerr << "Pipe failed." << endl;
    return (-1);
    }

    /* Create the child process. */
    parent_pid = getpid();
    pid = fork ();
    if (pid == (pid_t) 0) {
    /* child */
    pid = getpid();
    close(my_pipe[0]);
    cout << "I'm child " << j <<  "- my pid is " << pid <<
        " - my parent's pid is " << parent_pid << endl;
    if (i > 1) start_child(i - 1, j + 1);
    if (pid == getpid()) cout << "End of child "<< j << endl;
    close(my_pipe[1]);
    }
    else if (pid == (pid_t) -1) {
    perror("forking");
    close(my_pipe[0]);
    close(my_pipe[1]);
    return -1;
    }
    else {
    /* parent */
    close(my_pipe[1]);
    char buf[2];
    read(my_pipe[0], buf, 2); // wait for the child to close its pipe end
    close(my_pipe[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}



int main (void)
{
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    int i;

    cout << "\nassume father is by default the first process\n" << "Please enter how child-processes you want: ";
    cin >> i;

    cout << "I'm parent - my pid is " << pid << endl;

    int cr = start_child(i, 1);
    if (pid == getpid()) cout << "End of parent" << endl;
    return cr;
}// EOP
```

Comment: can you please vote my question so I collect more points and good reputation???
thanks